# How to start over the count on the year change?

Tags: java, android, count

I have a simple android app written in java. The app is a simple count app where I count different species of fish. To do so I implemented SQLite RoomDB. My table contains "ID", "f_type", "count", "time" e.g. 01, "sander", 2, "Dec 22, 2021 05:23:27pm". From each written record I calculated the total count based on fish type e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(count)FROM catch_table WHERE f_type = 'sander' ")
    LiveData<String> getSanderTotalCount();
```

All this works as aspected. However, I would like to start or reset my total count to zero when the year is changed. What would be the best practice to do so?
Thank you.

Comment: I would personally do searches by year, and that could be passed as a parameter to the SQL query - something like `getSanderTotalCount(String date)` and making sure the date is in the correct format :D

Answer (score 0):

lI would use the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) Interface:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Year;


public class Main {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
        scheduler.init();
    }
}

class Scheduler {
           
    public void init(){
        
        // specify interval (scheduled time - current time)        
        LocalDateTime current = LocalDateTime.now();           
        int year = Year.now().plusYears(1).getValue(); // increment current year to next year
        LocalDateTime schedule = LocalDateTime.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 1); // year, month, day, hour, minute
        
        // calculate duration
        Duration duration = Duration.between(current, schedule);
        long delay = Math.abs(duration.toMillis()); //or some other TimeUnit

        // reserve thread and schedule runnable task
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = executor.schedule(() -> {
            
             // run your code here

            init(); // reinitialize for next schedule
        }, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

[some examples](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/scheduledexecutorservice/)